# How to Check if a value exist in a Table,If it exists then Delete it?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, mysql-connector

I have a simple database named customer with a single table data.I want to check if a customer name exits in the database,if then i want to delete it.I'm using MYSQL Connector for this.

```
EDIT:
I want to make sure the value is present before deleting to display
a simple user message.
```

Comment: Did you try deleting a customer which exists and one which does not exist and see what happens??

Comment: This is a little confusing. do you want a MySQL query that will do that ? Do you pull the data into a datatable or something similar and would like to perfom the action on it? please expand.

Comment: You don't have to check for the existance of the data you want to delete, just delete it `where = your condition`

Comment: It could be as simple as `delete from customertable where name ='namehere'`, but is that all ?

Comment: Why dont you use 'Delete from where'?

Comment: @npinti Im not an expert in sql please help me out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just deleting it?

```
DELETE FROM customers WHERE customer_name = 'John Smith';
```

If it exists, it will be deleted. Otherwise no rows will be affected.

**EDIT:**

If you need a more complicated process, then I recommend (in order):

1. creating `ON DELETE FOR EACH ROW` trigger, that will auto update flags upon deletion;
2. developing a function/procedure for this purpose;
3. performing a set of actions within a transaction block, like:

```sql
    START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE flag_table SET is_deleted = 1 WHERE customer_name = 'John Smith';
    DELETE FROM customers WHERE customer_name = 'John Smith';
    COMMIT;
```

It would be easier to answer if you could provide more details on your design.

Comment: Wont this throw an exception if value is not found.

Comment: No. It simply don't do anything

Comment: I also want to check if the customer name exists.

Comment: @techno, so do you think your question is answered?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a trigger for this purpose, mysql will delete if any repetation is found on insertion.